# Finding a unit length vector that maximises a sums to zero for a linear equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I have a weight vector $w^T = [1, 4, 9]$
and the linear unit: $u = w^Tv$, where $u$ is the output.

q1) How do I find the unit length vector $v$ that maximises the output from the unit?

q2) Also how do I find the unit length vector $v$ which gives a 0 output from the linear unit?

**UPDATE:**

Would q1 just be [0, 0, 1]? As the last element of W has the largest value, thus it makes sense to maximise this value.

I made small amount of progress on q2. i.e. I am sure that

$a + 4b + 9c = 0$

and

$\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2} = 1$

But I am struggling to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) your answer is correct by intuitive arguments

2) There is not just one vector for which this is zero. 
Firstly indeed $a+4b+9c$ must be zero. Then you can for example take $c=0$. Now $a=-4b$. So a vector of the form $(-4,1,0)$ answers the demand. Now normalise this and you get $(-4/\sqrt{17},1/\sqrt{17},0)$, which is unit length. You can do the same by taking respectively $a$ and $b$ equal to zero. So the solution is not unique.

Comment: Out of curiosity, wouldn't [0, 0, 0] also be an answer?

Comment: Nope, not a unitary vector ;)

Comment: oh yeah silly question